# Nokia HERE Maps javascript API: Is there any property to fix the position of an infoBubble?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Currently we are using **HERE Javascript Api** 2.5.3 (https://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all) and created a `InfoBubbleMarker` - within custom html content - based on the description in nokias developers ApiExplorer (http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/information-bubbles/extend-marker-to-infobubblemarker.html)

While the `infoBubbles` automated position switch - depending on the fact, where is place to display it - is often kind of nice, we want to disable it.

So: Is there any `property` to `fix` the `position` of the `infoBubble`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultXAlignment` and `defaultYAlignment` properties to alter the preferred offset for the `Infobubble`  e.g.:

```
var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
infoBubbles.options.set("defaultXAlignment", 
    nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT);
infoBubbles.options.set("defaultYAlignment",
     nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_ABOVE);
map.components.add(infoBubbles);
```

This still doesn't *fix* the position of the `Infobubble` though, since it will still switch to the other side if there is insufficient space on the right side of the map to display the bubble.

To **completely fix** the position of the `Infobubble`, you will also need to add observers to `defaultXAlignment` and `defaultYAlignment`to ensure the value never changes:

```
infoBubbles.addObserver("defaultXAlignment", function (){
    this.set("defaultXAlignment",
        nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT);});
 infoBubbles.addObserver("defaultYAlignment", function (){
    this.set("defaultYAlignment",
        nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_ABOVE);});
```