# Here Maps Javascript API - Information bubble overlaying route polyline?

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

I render a map with a route from point A to point B and zoom to the bounding box of the route.

I also render an associated information bubble for point B (destination).
This specific portion of my application does not involve user intervention so it is completely unattended
The map is also printed
Point B is always different
using Enterprise Javascript API v2.5.4

My issue is that many times the info bubble overlays the route polyline which obstructs the route.

I see InfoBubble alignment options for left, right, above, below but these will not help as points are dynamic

Any suggestions on positioning of Info Bubble to assure it does not overlay route?

Comment: Use paragraphs for paragraphs, not bullets

Answer (score 1):

The `defaultXAlignment` and `defaultYAlignment` properties can be used to set a preferred position of the InfoBubble.

You can use the `defaultXAlignment` and `defaultYAlignment` properties to alter the preferred offset for the `Infobubble`  e.g.:

```
var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
infoBubbles.options.set("defaultXAlignment", 
    nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT);
infoBubbles.options.set("defaultYAlignment",
     nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles.ALIGNMENT_ABOVE);
map.components.add(infoBubbles);
```

In your case I would suggest the following.

- When you zoom to the `bounding box` of the route add a padding factor to ensure there is space to display the infoBubble. The simplest way would be to zoom out one more stop, but you could use the `padding` property of the `nokia.maps.map.Display` to ensure you have enough space when you `zoom()`. See
  [nokia.maps.map.Display.setPadding()](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html#topic-apiref__Display-setPadding-method)
- Secondly calculate the **bearing** between the start and endpoints:

  ```
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() { 
    // convert degrees to radians
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  function bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    lat1 = lat1.toRad(); lat2 = lat2.toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
    var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) -
    Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
    return Math.atan2(y, x);
  }
  ```
- If the result is between 0 and `Math.PI/2` you are travelling **North-East**  fix the Infobubble to display on the **right** and **above**.
- If the result is between `Math.PI/2` and `Math.PI` you are travelling **South-East**  fix the Infobubble to display on the **right** and **below**.
- If the result is between `-Math.PI` and `-Math.PI/2` you are travelling **South-West**  fix the Infobubble to display on the **left** and **below**.
- If the result is between `-Math.PI/2` and 0 you are travelling **North-West**  fix the Infobubble to display on the **left** and **above**.

You can find more information about completely fixing an `InfoBubble` the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515944/)